# bash nohup with two commands

Tags: bash, sh, nohup

I have a small function in my `bashrc` so I can run a script and have the ouput sent to my email when it finishes. The code is the following:

```
run() {
    email=example@gmail.com
    last="${!#}"
    rest="${@:1:($#-1)}"

    (nohup $rest &> $last < /dev/null; mail -s "$rest" "$email" < "$last") &
}
```

The function is used like this

```
run ./script.sh arg1 arg2 output
```

and it seems to be working most of the time, but sometimes the email does not get sent even though the script finished. I suspect it has to do with me closing the server terminal. In those cases, the script is still running because of the `nohup` but it does not send the email at the end. I'd really appreciate some pointers in order to get it working properly.

Comment: `rest="${@:1:($#-1)}"` is a bad idea -- you can't accurately represent an argument vector in a scalar, so this runs the risk of arguments being string-split improperly, glob-expanded, etc. You could use `rest=( "${@:1:($#-1)}" )`, though, and then expand it with `"${rest[@]}"` (or, for the single-argument subject-line version, `"${rest[*]}"`... or, more accurately, `printf -v rest_cmd '%q ' "${rest[@]}"`, then using `"$rest_cmd"` as the mail argument)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will definately change that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways to resolve this, but I think I would recommend this:

```
run() {
  email=example@gmail.com
  rest="${@:1:($#-1)}"

  nohup bash -c "$rest < /dev/null 2>&1 | mail -s \"$rest\" \"$email\"" &
}
```

The issue is your `nohup` command ended at the semicolon after `/dev/null` and thus didn't apply to the `mail` part. The `( ... )` introduces a subshell, but is not an external command, so `nohup ( ... )` wouldn't work, which is why `bash -c "..."` is required (you could also use `${SHELL} -c " ..."` for added portability if that's important). The double quotes you had need to be escaped when enclosed in another set of quotes. Also, the temporary file is not necessary (unless you wanted to keep it around for some reason - if that's the case, feel free to put the redirections back and separate the commands with `;` instead of `|`). Without needing the output file, you could also dispense with the `rest=...` bit and just call it as `run script.sh arg1 arg2`, but if you already have calls to it spread throughout other code, it might be simpler to leave that bit in - you'll have to figure that part out...

Comment: Thank! I actually tried ```nohup (...)``` and I was really confussed about it not working!

Comment: The output file was useful for me so I changed your script to ```nohup bash -c "$rest &> $last ; mail -s \"$rest\" \"$email\" < \"$last\"" &> /dev/null < /dev/null &```

The purpose of the ```< /dev/null``` was to avoid nohup warning message ```nohup: ignoring input```. For the same purpose, I added the ```&> /dev/null``` at the end.

Comment: Nice explanation of why the subshell option doesn't work.